# Java Graphics not showing

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to draw a traffic light. Basically a long rectangle shaped frame with 4 buttons attached to it. I've followed the instructions I've been given but I must be missing something. When I run the program I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TrafficLightPanel.<init>(TrafficLightPanel.java:14)
    at TrafficLightApp.main(TrafficLightApp.java:11)
```

Any help on this would be great ^^

Main method

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class TrafficLightApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Traffic Lights");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    TrafficLightPanel lightPanel = new TrafficLightPanel(); //line 11
    frame.add(lightPanel);//JFrame containing instance of TrafficLightPanel class

    }

}
```

Support class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class TrafficLightPanel extends JPanel{
    private JButton red,amber,green,change;
    private JLabel buttonLabel,lastPressed;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;

    public TrafficLightPanel(){
        //JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setSize(200,400);
        panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        buttonPanel.setSize(80,390); //line 14
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        buttonPanel.add(red);
        buttonPanel.add(amber);
        buttonPanel.add(green);
        buttonPanel.add(change);
        buttonPanel.add(buttonLabel);

        panel.add(buttonPanel);
    }
}
```

Comment: `buttonPanel.setSize(80,390);` this will likely be ignore by a layout manager.  A general tip:  Don't extend `JPanel` unless changing functionality.  The problem description suggests you are intending to do custom painting to one panel, but it should probably not have any 'child' controls of its own.  That custom painting panel can ***suggest*** a size by overriding `getPreferredSize()`, then add it and other controls to a 'parent' panel (again just an instance, not extended) and add the parent container to the GUI.  `frame.setVisible(true);` should be last, immediately after `frame.pack()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a **lot** of null variables, just because the reference variables declared at the top, does **not** mean they magically have an instance assigned to them, you still need to make `JComponent` Objects.

Since you instantiate `panel` but don't also instantiate `buttonPanel`, that's your first NPE. You also don't instantiate your JButtons, you simply add them to your `buttonPanel`, same thing with `buttonLabel` and `lastPressed` (but this var is unused).

Also, keep in mind that `TrafficLightPanel` is already a `JPanel`, you may be able to get rid of some redundancy.

So, basically you have to **instantiate** (using the `new` keyword) each and *every* variable declared at the top before you use it. Positioning will also be an issue, but it's not your current problem.

Comment: +1 especially for the line *"you may be able to get rid of some redundancy"*.